# Xpath - choose A if B is 0 else choose B

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to gather some informations from an estatepage and i've run into this logic problem before and now i'm asking for your help.

basicly it's there are two different ways the table with info i'm looking at

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Bolig areal</th> (estate size)
  <td>0 m</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Grund areal</th> (ground size)
  <td>5000 m</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Bolig areal</th> (estate size)
  <td>123 m</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Grund areal</th> (ground size)
  <td>5000 m</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the 'bolig areal'(estate size). But if 'bolig areal' is 0 m, then take Grund areal(ground size)

I'm currently stuck on an Xpath expression like:

```
//div[@class='description-element description-info shadow']//th[contains(.,'Grund areal') or contains(.,'Bolig areal')]/following-sibling::td/text()[not(contains(.,'0 m'))]
```

Where I select both the `<th>`, selects the following `<td>/text`, where the text is != 0m.
Which selects the Ground area.

How do I add the "if 'Bolig areal' is different from 0 m pick 'Bolig areal', otherwise use 'Ground areal'

solution:

```
".//tr[th = 'Bolig areal' and td != '0 m' or th = 'Grund areal' and not(ancestor::table/tr[th = 'Bolig areal' and td != '0 m'])]/td/text()"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```xml
//tr[th = 'Bolig areal' and td != '0 m' or th = 'Grund areal' and not(ancestor::table/tr[th = 'Bolig areal' and td != '0 m'])]/td
```

This selects the **tr** that has either `th = 'Bolig areal' and td != '0 m'` or the **tr** that has `th = 'Grund areal'` if the first expression `th = 'Bolig areal' and td != '0 m'` is not true for the current table. From that selected **tr** the **td** is selected.

Comment: Please elaborate on why you think this answer might solve the problem, instead of just dropping some code.

Comment: @NiekHaarman I usually do, but this is just a chain of boolean expressions and I think self explanatory if you read and try to understand it.

Comment: Sure. Then again, a chain of boolean expressions can be hard to understand in the first place. Formatting and/or splitting up helps in that case. In general, I try to explain the answer so the asker can figure it out for themselves the next time :)

Comment: @NiekHaarman there you go... I tryed ...however I still think it's easier to understand the code than the explanation ;)

Comment: Hi @TobiasKlevenz This solved the puzzle. I used : ".//tr[th = 'Bolig areal' and td != '0 m' or th = 'Grund areal' and not(ancestor::table/tr[th = 'Bolig areal' and td != '0 m'])]/td/text()" in order to get it done. I did like to thank choroba aswell for his hardwork.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
//table[tr[th="Bolig areal"][td != "0 m"]]/tr[th="Bolig areal"]/td/text()
|
//table[tr[th="Bolig areal"][td = "0 m"]]/tr[th="Grund areal"]/td/text()
```

This is essentially a translation of:

- if a `table` contains a row with a "Bolig areal" `th` that has a value (`td`) different from "0 m", pick that value (`td/text()`)
- alternatively (`|` operator), if the "Bolig areal" value is "0 m", select the value from the row with header "Grund areal"

You could use `contains(th, "Bolig areal")` instead of `th="Bolig areal"`

Example Python session with lxml (libxml2):

```
In [1]: import lxml.html

In [2]: doc1 = lxml.html.fromstring("""<table>
   ...: <tr>
   ...:   <th>Bolig areal</th> (estate size)
   ...:   <td>0 m</td>
   ...: </tr>
   ...: <tr>
   ...:   <th>Grund areal</th> (ground size)
   ...:   <td>5000 m</td>
   ...: </tr>
   ...: </table>""")

In [3]: doc2 = lxml.html.fromstring("""<table>
   ...: <tr>
   ...:   <th>Bolig areal</th> (estate size)
   ...:   <td>123 m</td>
   ...: </tr>
   ...: <tr>
   ...:   <th>Grund areal</th> (ground size)
   ...:   <td>5000 m</td>
   ...: </tr>
   ...: </table>""")

In [4]: xp = lxml.etree.XPath("""//table[tr[th="Bolig areal"][td != "0 m"]]/tr[th="Bolig areal"]/td/text()
   ...: |
   ...: //table[tr[th="Bolig areal"][td = "0 m"]]/tr[th="Grund areal"]/td/text()""")

In [5]: xp(doc1)
Out[5]: ['5000 m']

In [6]: xp(doc2)
Out[6]: ['123 m']

In [7]:
```

Comment: If I have tested it correctly, would it return 0 in the first table insted of 5000 ? or am I mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You want the first `th` that is not followed by `0 m`, then extract the first following `td`:

```
//th[(.='Bolig areal' and following-sibling::td!='0 m') or (.='Grund areal' and ../..//th[.='Bolig areal']/following-sibling::td='0 m')]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have updated the ticket, with another table and my full (wrong) expression.

Comment: for each table, the following works for me: `(tr/th[contains(.,'Grund areal') or contains(.,'Bolig areal')][following-sibling::td[1]!="0 m"])[1]/following-sibling::td[1]`

Comment: If I use //div[@class='description-element description-info shadow']//th[contains(.,'Grund areal') or contains(.,'Bolig areal')][following-sibling::td[1]!="0 m"][1]/following-sibling::td[1] on the second table I get two <td> insted of a single which should be 'Bolig areal'::td, I noticed you changed the start (tr/, I basicly need it to start with //th

Comment: Ahh, I think you have misunderstood me (or I havn't been clear enough) I want 'Bolig area' if it is != 0 m. And if 'Bolig area' is == 0 m then take 'Grund area' insted. Not "You want the first th that is not followed by 0 m,"

Comment: @user3489698: I tried to translate your wording to XPath. Check again.

Comment: The update works perfect for second table. But it takes 'Bolig areal' on the first table.

Comment: @user3489698: Works for me, returns the two nodes 5000 and 123.